# Imported Enum class is not comparing equal to itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

In my code, I was puzzled by `Enum` instances with the same value not comparing equal. I quickly realized that their `id(...)` were different. Later, much less quickly, I realized that the only change since it last worked was the `import` statement: using explicit module path rather than relative.

Then I came up with this isolated example.

```
$ ls
e/

$ ls e
__init__.py  __pycache__/  m1.py  m1.pyc  m2.py

$  python3 --version
Python 3.5.1

$ cat e/m1.py
from enum import Enum
class E(Enum):
    x=0

$ cat e/m2.py
from m1 import E as E1
from e.m1 import E as E2

print(id(E1), id(E1.x))
print(id(E2), id(E2.x))
```

Let's run it:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=~/test python3 e/m2.py
41536520 42656096
41537464 42656488
```

Obviously, equality (which is by identity for `Enum`) does not hold. Anyone else out there find this troubling?

Let me elaborate. Adding two more files:

```
$ cat e/file1.py
from m1 import E

class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = E.x
```

One more. Note the difference in imports.

```
$ cat e/file2.py
from e.m1 import E
from file1 import C

c = C()
print(c.x, E.x)
print('Surprise! ->', c.x is E.x)
```

Both are valid imports. Now run it.

```
$ PYTHONPATH=~/test python3 e/file2.py
E.x E.x
Surprise! -> False
```

How can I avoid this trap? Is there a reason why I should not be troubled by this?

Comment: Using `is` is not comparing, it is an identity check.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Later, much less quickly, I realized that the only change since it last worked was the `import` statement: using explicit module path rather than relative.

Python 3 doesn't have implicit relative imports. Your "relative" import is actually **another absolute import**. You're importing two completely distinct modules, `m1` and `e.m1`, that happen to come from the same file.

If you want to use a relative import in Python 3, you need to make it explicit:

```
from .m1 import E
#    ^ explicit relative import
```

If you run the program as

```
python3 -m e.m2
```

you'll avoid the problems with the module search path that allowed both `m1` and `e.m1` to exist. You can also manually fix `sys.path` and set [`__package__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) from `e/m2.py`.

Comment: `import sys;print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.modules)))` does indeed show `m1` and `e.m1` modules. But what puzzles me is how python found `m1` in the first place. I thought implicit relative imports were disallowed since python 3.3.

Comment: @tdelaney: It's an absolute import, not a relative import. The `e` directory and its parent are both on the module search path, so the same files are found two ways by the import logic.

Comment: Oh yeah. its the base script's directory. I've always hated that feature and I'm still good at blocking it out! I avoid putting my top level scripts in packages anyway so I tend not to notice.

Comment: That and the `__main__` thing are the big things that annoy me about the import system. I wish Python picked some other way of distinguishing the main script, and I wish it wasn't possible to get a directory and one of its subdirectories both on the module search path.

Answer (score 8):

This is not an issue with `Enum`, but with python imports.  If you import the same module with a different name, you get two different modules.

Try, for example, `E1 is E2`.

Comment: Yes, it has more to do with imports, but the problem becomes apparent with Enum because one rarely compares other type of objects by identity.